# Postgres - User defined order sequence

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a column in a database table that may contain one of a limited amount of strings: ["Recht", "Abteilung", "Strecke", "Stelle", "Gemarkung", ...].

I want to perform queries to the table that order the result according to this column, but not alphanumerical but user-defined, i.e. "Recht" before "Abteilung" followed by "Strecke" ...

Is it possible to use a user-defined order like this?

Comment: order by case when column='Recht' then 1 when column='Abteilung' then 2 end case  Something like this

Comment: No need to downvote though, this is a valid question with a useful answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to do this in Postgres uses arrays:

```
order by array_position(array['Recht', 'Abteilung', 'Strecke', 'Stelle', 'Gemarkung'], 'a_column') nulls last
```

The use of an array makes the logic quite concise -- and more maintainable.  The array can also be passed in as a parameter, which can be quite convenient.